# Capsule shape using border-radius without a set width or height?

Tags: css, css-shapes

Is it possible to make a capsule shape using border-radius without a set width or height?

I want the left and right sides to be completely rounded while the capsule would remain straight along it's horizontal length. Setting the radius to 50% doesn't seem to give the desired affect.

[image: Capsule Shape]

Comment: You could do the desired math using a server side language or javascript and generate it appropriately from there.

Comment: This is an option. Just seems like overkill for something so presentational. I'm looking to use this for buttons so I might be able to make some headway using ems.

Comment: This question explains how this works : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966499/border-radius-in-percentage-and-pixels-px

Comment: Does it have to use border-radius?  You could also do this with 3 background properties (2 radial-gradients for the ends)

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Applying a very large border radius seems to work on many browsers (IE9+, FF, Chrome) like this mod of David's fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cthQW/1/

```
border-radius: 500px;
```

Comment: Could this be the answer? [Corner curves must not overlap: When the sum of any two adjacent border radii exceeds the size of the border box, UAs must proportionally reduce the used values of all border radii until none of them overlap.](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds/#corner-overlap)

Comment: Absolutely! Nicely found, and a very impressive (and simple) solution; have a deserved upvote =)

Comment: It's nice to think it's perhaps not a hack after all, and that would explain why all the browsers I've observed so far behave the same.

Comment: Why does this work but a large percentage doesn't work?

Comment: @CaldwellYSR I assume that when using percentages the vertical radius is computed based on the elements height and the horizontal radius is calculated based on the elements width. Whereas a fixed unit does not vary in that way. Here's a [border-radius fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qBSb/30/) that visualizes differences between fixed units and percentages.

Answer (score 28):

Yes, this is possible (albeit I've only tested in Chromium 28/Ubuntu 12.10):

```
div {
    /* this is the only relevant part: */
    border-radius: 20%/50%;

    /* this is irrelevant, and just so the element can be visualised/displayed: */
    width: 50%;
    height: 5em;
    margin: 2em auto;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5qBSb/).

The important information is, obviously, the `20%/50%` property-value; the `20%` is the 'horizontal length' of the radius, whereas the `50%` is the 'vertical length'; using two different measurements gives an elliptical curve to the border, instead of a single measurement, which yields the more circular radius. Obviously this requires a certain amount of adjustment to your own requirements

References:

- [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) (at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/)).
- [CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3: 5.1. Curve Radii: the ‘border-radius’ properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius).

Comment: Okay, I see your point; but that's always a problem of using `border-radius` (that the content isn't necessarily 'contained' within the border's curve. Using [`padding` can help](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5qBSb/2/), though; Or [a child element, with a `margin`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5qBSb/3/).

Comment: this doesn't work if you don't want to round *all* the borders

Comment: Yeah this isn't exactly what you want

Answer (score 9):

If you use percentages, it takes the element width to calculate the radius. To have the capsule-shaped element, you need to pass to the `border-radius` property units like **rem** or **px** (neither I know the reason for this, but it works). This is why it works when passing **500px**. You can use the same value for `line-height` and `border-radius` properties if you want.

```
.capsule {
    line-height: 48px;
    border-radius: 48px;
}
```

Here you have an example in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/timbergus/pen/yYyvEb). Try to change the variable `$label-height` to see how the shape is maintained while the height of the button changes.

In this example, you don't need to set the width or height of the element. You just need to adjust the content's `height` and `padding`.

The padding property is useful to set a separation between the contents and the component border. See how it looks if I only set the left padding.

[image]

If you set the `line-height` property of the container, you will set automatically the container height, and center the content inside the container at the same time.

If you want to set the component's width to the component's content width, you can set the component's display property to `inline-block`, and use FlexBox to arrange them in a column, for example. And then, set the left and right margins to auto, to avoid the element to grow to its parent width.

[image]

And if you want to leave a space between the components, you can set the `margin-top` property between consecutive components.

```
.capsule + .capsule {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily achieved using HTML Span. You have to just set the background-color and border-radius.

```css
span {
  background-color: #30bb36;
  border-radius: 10px;  
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Set a <span>Background Color</span> for only a part of a text.</p>
    <span>One</span>
    <span>Two</span>
    <span>Three</span>
    <span>Four</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not work well for anything but the default font-size.

Answer (score 0):

To get capsule shape you can set the border radius to height of an element.

So if

`height: 5rem;`

than set

`border-radius: 5rem;`

If you use some padding or border set
`box-sizing: border-box;`
this includes the padding and border into an element's total height

Answer (score -3):

This is what I have found to work well:

`border-radius: 50vh;`

Browser support looks good for that now too.

To explain, the `vh` is a "Viewport Unit" that computes the **height** of the viewport in pixels. By saying `50vh` to declare the border radius, it is `50% * (Viewport Height)px`.

Comment: Please add an explanation for your answer.

Comment: This isn't right. It works because 50vh is half the height of the *screen*, and that is larger than the maximum radius so it truncated to the correct radius. If you do 1000vh it will behave the same.

Comment: I explained the screen height in my answer. It usually works fine for me, but you may be correct in that the `1000vh` is more likely to work for larger elements.

Comment: I think @Timmmm's point is there's nothing magic about the 50 here. This works only as a consequence of Jeremy Cook's answer to use a big value; 40vh or 60vh or 1000vh would all work just as well for a typical (ie small-ish) element.

Comment: “[_Correlation does not imply causation_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation).” No magic about the `50`.