# Avoid elliptical shape in CSS border-radius

Tags: html, css

Using Border-radius CSS for rectangular divs produces elliptical corners instead of rounded corners. How can I get perfect rounded corners for rectangular divs?

Comment: Every div is rectangular ... The shape of the corners is solely defined by the values for `border-radius`.

Comment: @zeroflagL OP meant "rectangular" as opposed to "square"... e.g., any div whose aspect ratio is not 1:1.

Comment: For people wanting a pill shape, ie a rectangle with fully rounded corners, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18795153/18706

Comment: This explains how it works : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966499/border-radius-in-percentage-and-pixels-px

Comment: OH. I was trying to figure out why my rectangle's corners were looking crappy (I *hate* the "elliptic arc" look, they should just remove it altogether...). Turns out using a % instead of a px value for `border-radius` was the culprit.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

[image: image from MDN]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/files/3638/border-radius-sh.png))</sub>

Formally, the syntax for the border-radius property accepts 2 values for each corner: a horizontal radius and a vertical radius (separated by a slash). The following line would create an elliptical border-radius similar to the third image above.

```
border-radius: 10px / 5px;
```

Usually, we only specify one value. In this case, that value gets used as both the vertical and horizontal radii. The following line would create a circular border-radius similar to the second image above.

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

---

**Using Percentages**

The [Mozilla Developer's Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) defines the possible value types for this property as follows:

> **<length>**
> Denotes the size of the circle radius or the semi-major and semi-minor axes of the ellipsis. It can be expressed in any unit allowed by the CSS  data types. Negative values are invalid.
>
> **<percentage>**
> Denotes the size of the circle radius, or the semi-major and semi-minor axes of the ellipsis, using percentage values. **Percentages for the horizontal axis refer to the width of the box, percentages for the vertical axis refer to the height of the box.** Negative values are invalid.

Using a single value to create a circular radius is fine when we're using absolute `length` units like pixels or ems, but gets more complicated when we're using percentages. Since the single-value usage of this property is synonymous with using the same value twice, the following two lines are equivalent; however, these would not necessarily create a circular border-radius.

```
border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%/50%;
```

These lines say the border is defined by an ellipse whose vertical radius is equal to 50% of the element's height and whose horizontal radius is equal to 50% of the element's width. If the element is 200 pixels wide and 100 pixels tall, this results in an ellipse rather than a circle.

---

**Solution**

If you want a circular border-radius, the easiest thing to do is to use absolute measurement units (like pixels or ems or anything besides percentage), but sometimes that doesn't fit your use case and you want to use percentages. If you know the aspect-ratio of the containing element, you still can! In the example below, since my element is twice as wide as it is tall, I've scaled the horizontal radius in half.

```css
#rect {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 25%/50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="rect"></div>
```

Another option is to provide a sufficiently huge value any absolute measurement unit. If the value exceeds half of the shortest side's length, the browser will use the minimum as its border-radius in both directions, producing a perfect pill shape on rectangular elements.

```css
#rect {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100vmax;
}
```

```html
<div id="rect"></div>
```

Comment: For me the issue was using a percentage for the border radius, changing this to a pixel value solved it. I only had to read the beginning of your answer before it dawned on me that 50% of the height was different than 50% of the width.

Comment: that last trick was what I was looking for, thanks! 

this is very useful when you have content that may cause the rectangular shape to change in height due to unknown content lengths and/or the width of the container at a specific responsive viewport width

Comment: Or we can use
border-radius: 1̶0̶0̶0̶0̶0̶0̶0̶0̶0̶0̶0̶0̶0̶0̶p̶x̶  100vmax;

Answer (score 16):

`border-radius: 9999px` does produce 'perfect 1/4 circle' corners, that's why you can make css circles with this property. They sometimes don't look like they are perfectly round corners, but that's an optical illusion. If this bothers you, you can try to imitate the effect with something like `border-radius: 9px / 8px`

`border-radius: 50%` will, on the other hand, produce non-circular arcs if your div is not square. Again, you can override behavior you don't like by specifying separate radii for x and y axis like `border-radius: 10% / 20%`.

Comment: The `9999px` is used by Tailwind CSS by the way. This way you can apply the utility `rounded-full` onto a rectangular div and end up with a "pill" shape.

Comment: loved that 9999px solution!

Comment: This is the way

Comment: Works until we invent a screen that has more than 50,000 pixels in height.  I feel that `100vh` would be more dynamic, and.. er, future-proof.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a percent it can cause that stretching/elliptical appearance.  You may want to try designating the units in px for more of a customized rounded look.

Answer (score 4):

Just define the radius using vw/vh (worked for me at least):

```css
button{
    border-radius:1vh;
}
```

This works as vh / vw are always constant to the viewport and independant of the element :)

Answer (score 4):

adding to Kelvin's answer,
to get perfectly round corners on a rectangle, try:

```
button {
    border-radius: 50vh;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that affects the border radius is, ironically, border.... if you have a border-top and no border on the sides, you'll see the same lopsided border rounding effect as you get when you use percentage-based radius.

I can see this being a useful feature. But please, please, put a comment in your CSS to tell future-you (or others) why you're doing it. Debugging this was painful!

Answer (score 1):

```
style={{ 
        height: "150px", 
        width: "150px", 
        borderRadius: "50%", 
        boxSizing: "border-box", 
        overflow: "hidden"                         
}}
```

This is what that relieved me from annoying **OVAL Shape** problem.

- this is inline CSS.

Comment: this is not css this is inlined React.CSSProperties object

Comment: yes, I should've mentioned that this is inline CSS of react.

Comment: Technically it is something that will transform into CSS. It doesn't serve any purpose here to write it as inline React.CSSProperties when answering the question, since none of the properties are dynamic. It can be replaced with the final CSS output in the answer. As for your answer, this just forces the object to take a square shape, and obviously a square with 50% `border-radius` becomes a circle. It doesn't work for rectangles though, which is specifically what the question is for. In short, it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .box {
            width: 50px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            aspect-ratio: 1;
            resize: both;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <script>
        const ro = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
            for (let entry of entries) {
                entry.target.style.borderRadius = entry.target.style.width;
            }
        });
        ro.observe(document.querySelector('.box'));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```