# Is it possible to create rectangle with its left and right sides are absolute circle by using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here what I'm trying to create is shown in the image
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZIEJ.png]

I have used `border-radius` but it didn't helped me. what I have done so far is given on the snippet below:

```css
.button-holder{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
}
.button{
    width:80%;
    height:65%;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:2px solid #000;
    background-color:#063755;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-holder">
   <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

> Please Note:- I know that it's possible to obtain the shape by merging
>   multiple `<div>` tags,but it will not help me. I looking for an answer
>   with a single `<div>` tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capsule shape using border-radius without a set width or height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794947/capsule-shape-using-border-radius-without-a-set-width-or-height)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use half the height in `px`, not `%`.

```css
.button-holder{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
}
.button{
    width:80%;
    height:65%;
    border-radius:32.5px;  // 100px * 0.65 * 0.5 = 32.5px
    border:2px solid #000;
    background-color:#063755;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-holder">
   <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can express this as `border-radius: calc(100px * 0.65 * 0.5);` rather than doing the calculation yourself.

Comment: Good call, that's another option.

Answer (score 1):

you can use psuedo elements like this:

```css
.button-holder {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #063755;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button-holder:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%; /* height/width */
  top: 0;
  left: -16.665%; /* 1/2 of the width */
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #063755;
}

.button-holder:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  top: 0;
  right: -16.665%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #063755;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-holder">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #corner {
      border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
      background: #73AD21;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 400px;
      height: 150px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="corner"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kk5S.jpg)