# How to get rounded corners on my Safari-rendered Apple Pay button?

Tags: html, css, safari, applepay

Is there a way to put rounded corners on a Safari-rendered Apple Pay button (using `-webkit-appearance: -apple-pay-button`)?

I know Apple are very strict about what you can and cannot do with Apple Pay buttons, but they [specifically say that you should adjust the corner radius to match the appearance of other buttons](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/apple-pay/overview/buttons-and-marks/):

> You can change the corner radius to produce a button with square corners or a pill-shaped button.

Now, all my buttons are pill-shaped, so I guess the Apple Pay button should be as well. However, I'm stumped on how to do this in the browser, since `border-radius` seems to be ignored for elements with `-webkit-appearance: -apple-pay-button`.

Here's an example (which for obvious reasons **only works in Safari**), uncheck the checkbox to see what corner style I'm after:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Apple Pay button test</title>
    <style>
      * {
        font-size: 24px;
      }
      .ap-button {
        border-radius: 1000000px; /* https://stackoverflow.com/a/18795153 */
        display: block;
      }
      input:checked ~ .ap-button {
        color: transparent; /* Hide text */
        -webkit-appearance: -apple-pay-button; /* Make Safari render it specially */
      }
      input:not(:checked) ~ .ap-button {
        border: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" checked> Render as Apple Pay button
    <button class="ap-button">
       Pay
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds so strange, but, since apple is apple, i'd guess your best bet would be to just get an image of the apple pay button and apply the border radius to that. Would probably be the least time-consuming route in this case.

Comment: @Joel perhaps, but I'm also not entirely sure that'd be in line with Apple's 
Human Interface Guidelines.

Comment: Dont think they’ll sue you for applying a border radius to their button. Could be wrong lol

Comment: @Joel nah they probably won't but they actually say: _Don't create your own Apple Pay button design or attempt to mimic the system-provided button designs._ https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/apple-pay/overview/buttons-and-marks/ ... so the simplest thing is probably accepting the non-rounded corners if they can't be restyled :)

Comment: Yeah, it’s unfortunate but there’s not many other options than what I proposed, I guess it’s that or letting it go completely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was to just remove the webkit applied styles and use the apple provided styles for browsers that don't support -webkit-appearance. This worked just fine (note that my radius and width are different).

```
    .apple-pay-button {
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 100% 60%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    border-radius: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-width: 115px;
    min-height: 32px;
    max-height: 64px;
}
.apple-pay-button-black {
    background-image: -webkit-named-image(apple-pay-logo-white);
    background-color: black;
}
.apple-pay-button-white {
    background-image: -webkit-named-image(apple-pay-logo-black);
    background-color: white;
}
.apple-pay-button-white-with-line {
    background-image: -webkit-named-image(apple-pay-logo-black);
    background-color: white;
    border: .5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: That's actually quite clever in its simplicity. Although it doesn't exactly answer the question as posed, this is probably the only way to get a rounded button while still following Apple's guidelines. Accepted it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this webkit


-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
```

Comment: No, this has no effect. `border-radius` generally works fine in Safari (and it has worked without prefix for the last 10 years), it's just for the specially-rendered Apple Pay buttons it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding a background color to the button's css. In my case, I was using the black button style.

Tested on iOS 13.3.1

```
@supports (-webkit-appearance: -apple-pay-button) { 
    button.apple-pay-button {
        display: inline-block;
        -webkit-appearance: -apple-pay-button;
        background: #000;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    .apple-pay-button-black {
        -apple-pay-button-style: black;
    }
}
```

Kind Regards,